# Join more than two tables with "not in" clause

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010

Can you please show me where I can INNER JOIN the tables for the FK_roomTypesID, FK_BedTypeID and FK_roomViewsID? All of the FK are on different tables from the primary.

```
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT RoomNo, RoomBedsNo, 
    RoomSmoking, RoomMiniBar,RoomKitchen,RoomFirePlace,RoomBalcony, RoomVeranda,
    RoomGarden, RoomEntrance, RoomAirCondition, RoomTV, FK_roomTypesID, 
    FK_BedTypeID, FK_roomViewsID FROM tblrooms WHERE roomsID NOT IN(SELECT FK_roomsID
    FROM tblbooking WHERE '" + arrdate + "' < checkOutDate AND '" + depdate + "' > 
    checkInDate)", conn);
```

Comment: Can you show us your database model please?

Comment: No, we cannot tell you that because we cannot read your mind or see the tables in your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following part in your query:

```
FROM tblrooms
```

You define your `join`s in your `FROM` clause, therefore you should modify the code above to something like:

```
FROM tblrooms
join tblroomtypes
on tblrooms.FK_roomTypesID = tblroomtypes.roomTypesID
join tblbedtypes
on tblrooms.FK_bedTypesID = tblbedtypes.bedTypesID
join tblroomviews
on tblrooms.FK_roomViewsID = tblroomviews.roomViewsID
```

Note, that you did not give too much information, so I am guessing your `table` and `column` names here. Also, note, that I did not select any new `columns`. Finally, note, that you need to resolve ambiguity if the problem is applicable to your case by referring to your `columns` as `table`'s columns. And format your code, it is difficult to read it. I did not use the `inner` keyword for the `joins`, because `join` is `inner` by default.

Comment: nicely done... sometimes those who post are ambiguous and we have to make educated accurate guesses to what they have/need.  They too will learn to adjust their future questions to cover a bit more detail.